# Hook frame to mode in emacs

Tags: emacs, hook, frame

Using emacs -nw I would like to make hooks so that certain modes (for writing prose) gives me a narrow centered frame. This

```
(set-frame-width (selected-frame) 100)
```

... sets a narrower frame but aligned to the left.

How do I center it? 
And how do I set a hook that changes the frame when I switch mode?

Comment: Perhaps [writeroom-mode](http://melpa.milkbox.net/#/writeroom-mode) does something like what you want.

Comment: Here is an example using a particular major mode hook, which sets the frame position at the upper left-hand corner.  You can play around with the the two numbers that are x y axis coordinates until you get what you want.  If you have different resolutions and your are looking for Emacs to calculate the screen resolution and then center your frame based upon it being a certain size, well, that is possible, but would need to be written.  `(add-hook 'text-mode-hook (lambda () (set-frame-height (selected-frame) 20) (set-frame-width (selected-frame) 80) (set-frame-position (selected-frame) 0 0) ))`

Comment: With regards to calculating the screen resolution and frame position, take a look at two related libraries written by @Drew .  They can ascertain the screen resolution and set frame positions based thereon.  I'm sure there is something there that you can modify to suit your needs -- there are three tile frame functions in particular that look like they would be a good place for you to start.  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/frame-fns.el  and  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/frame-cmds.el

Answer (score 0):

Try using the hooks `after-make-frame-functions` and `after-change-major-mode-hook`.

(Dunno how much these will help with `emacs -nw`, though.)

Answer (score 0):

The following link to a gist on Github written by @ieure appears to resolve your issue as to centering:

https://gist.github.com/ieure/80638

---

See also the following two (2) libraries written by @Drew:

http://emacswiki.org/emacs/frame-fns.el

http://emacswiki.org/emacs/frame-cmds.el

---

Here are a few examples.  On a screen with 1920 x 1080 pixels, my maximum `frame-height` is 52 and my maximum `frame-width` is 172.  The function below that is named `minimize` changes the size of all open frames and places the reduced frames to the left side of the screen, because I like to type notes in Emacs while I'm looking at another application -- e.g., Adobe Acrobat.

When using `set-frame-position`, the numbers are x and y coordinates starting with the upper left-hand corner of the screen. For example, a frame with `(set-frame-position (selected-frame) 300 300)` will be to the lower-right of another frame with `(set-frame-position (selected-frame) 0 0)`.

```lisp
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook (lambda ()
  (set-frame-height (selected-frame) 20)
  (set-frame-width (selected-frame) 80)
  (set-frame-position (selected-frame) 400 400) ))

(defun minimize ()
(interactive)
  (dolist (frame (frame-list))
    (set-frame-height frame 52)
    (set-frame-width frame 50)
    (set-frame-position frame 0 0) ))

(defun maximize ()
(interactive)
  (dolist (frame (frame-list))
    (set-frame-height frame 52)
    (set-frame-width frame 172)
    (set-frame-position frame 0 0) ))
```

Comment: Will try when I get home. Problem that I experienced at last try was that '(set-frame-position frame 400 400) ))' doesn't take effect in emacs -nw (I'm using emacs on a no-X machine) ...

Comment: Checked out the gists but haven't find a way to make the resized frame anything but left-aligned ...